# Some help with 9V Longlife VARTA batteries?

Tags: led, batteries, switches, heat-protection

I recently tried to make my own LED circuit to give some light to my room at night.I ended up with a circuit that goes like this:

- A 9V battery with clips goes to a SWITCH and from the switch to a POTENTIOMETER (so that i can operate the voltage-light of the LEDs). Now from the potentiometer it goes to a 220 Ohm RESISTOR that's connected to a LED. From this LED it goes in serie to another RESISTOR that is connecter to a LED. At last another RESISTOR comes from the 2nd LED (in serie) and goes back to the SWITCH and my 9V battery(in order to protect her?).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBa1Yf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Well i'm not good at schematics but it looks like this i think.
Anyway..my circuit worked well at first with the 9V battery but it made the battery really hot even when the switch was on the OFF mode. So i thought that could be a problem and i unplugged the battery from its clips. An hour later i put the battery back turned the switch to ON and tried again and it also worked as well.But at night my battery was dead.I thought i had a problem with my circuit,but i didnt. So then i unplugged the battery and plugged in a new one also 9V similar to the previous one.This one had the same problem with the previous except that this one was used for 3 hours instead of 30 minutes.

- So my main problem is that these "Longlife" batteries were both dead in so little time!!!
  Why is this happening? I cant keep on spending money to batteries.
  Do i have to change the last Resistor to a bigger one to "protect" the battery?

*Thank you for your help and time.*

Comment: Connecting both battery terminals together will kill the battery eventually, regardless of what "longlife" means.

Comment: When the switch is in the low position, the battery is shorted (according to your schematic).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Well,thats not exactly how it is(in reallity) i think i've put them good because as i said it was actually working but maybe you're right i'll check it tomorrow... thank you!

Comment: @NickAlexeev You're maybe saying the same thing with Ignacio above but it works when its in low position but this just heats the battery too much.

Comment: If shorting the battery and killing it "works" for you, then your understanding of "works" is quite different from mine.

Comment: Sorry,you're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably shorting out the battery when the switch is in the 'off' position- the schematic you show won't work (battery is shorted either way), so the real schematic must be a bit different.

Use the below schematic. Only two connections to the switch (leave the other one open) and only on one side of the battery.

[image: schematic]

It still won't be great- you'll most likely get much better performance in light per unit of currency by using 6 AA batteries in series rather than a 9V battery.

Comment: Yes yes exactly thats my problem! "The SWITCH and the BATTERY connection" ! I really dont know what to do.My switch as it is right now has 3 connections and its confusing me. I have let the 3rd side alone and solder to the one on the center my (+) from battery and a wire that goes on the potentiometer and to the right side of the switch i got the (-) of the battery and a wire coming from the last resistor of my schematic.
Thanks for your answer!

Comment: With the LEDs in series, you only need one current-limiting resistor, as Spehro's schematic shows.  If you have LEDs in parallel, you need a resistor for each of the parllel LEDs.

Comment: No,mine's actually in serie too..